# How can I stop Vim from writing a file without throwing an error?

Tags: save, autocmd, error

I'm trying to improve the code from [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/678/how-do-i-save-a-file-in-a-directory-that-does-not-yet-exist/679#679) to ask for confirmation before creating the missing directory, this is what I write:

```
function! CreateDirectoryAskConfirmation(path)
    if !isdirectory(a:path)
        echohl Question
        echo "Create directory " . a:path . "?"
        echohl None

        let response = nr2char(getchar())
        if response ==? "y"
            call mkdir(a:path, "p")
        endif
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufWritePre * call CreateDirectoryAskConfirmation(expand("<afile>:p:h"))
```

One thing I'm missing: when I don't press `y` at the prompt I'd like Vim to abort the write so I don't get the error `E212: Can't open file for writing` and I don't need to hit another key to make the error message disappear. There is a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of using the `BufWritePre` autocmd, you can use the `BufWriteCmd`
autocmd, from `:help BufWriteCmd`:

> Should do the writing of the file and reset 'modified' if successful, unless
>   '+' is in 'cpo' and writing to another file cpo-+.

We can just call `:write` from the autocmd. This will take care of setting `modified`.

So the logic would then be modified to call `:write` when the directory already exist, and call `:write` after creating the directory if it doesn't exist yet. If you press `n`, we do nothing. This will leave the buffer as-is, and won't re-set `modified`, so `:q` will still give you a `E37: No write since last change` error.

```
function! CreateDirectoryAskConfirmation(path, dir)
    silent doautocmd BufWritePre

    " Directory exists, :write and return
    if isdirectory(a:dir)
        execute 'write ' . a:path
        silent doautocmd BufWritePost
        return
    endif

    " Ask for confirmation to create this directory
    echohl Question
    echo "Create directory `" . a:dir . "' [y/N]?"
    echohl None

    let response = nr2char(getchar())
    " mkdir() and :write if we want to make a directory
    if response ==? "y"
        call mkdir(a:dir, "p")
        execute 'write ' . a:path
        silent doautocmd BufWritePost
    endif
endfunction

autocmd BufWriteCmd * call CreateDirectoryAskConfirmation(expand("<amatch>:p"), expand("<amatch>:p:h"))
```

Comment: In VimScript files, the leading `:` is never necessary for commands.

Comment: @tommcdo Thanks. For some reason my brain forgets this sometimes >_<

Comment: I've discovered a flaw in your answer so I have to un-accept it, see my answer for more details. Thank you for the great help.

Comment: @toro2k Thanks. I didn't know about that. I edited my answer, I also added `silent` so you won't get a message if you're not using this `autogroup`. I also fixed another problem I noticed: `:w another_name` didn't work (not it works).

Comment: Definetly better! Thank you! Just a question, why you have used `write filename` instead of just `write`?

Comment: @toro2k Because otherwise `write` will just write to current filename (just like when you type `:write`), and `:write another_filename` won't work (it will still use the original filename).

Comment: O yes, now I understand! :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thank you very much for your awesome answer. I start using your code a month ago and I found out that it saves "quickfix" as a file without asking any confirmation. Is there a way to not save "quickfix"?

Comment: @whitesiroi You can use the `bufype` setting to get the buffer type. Feel free to edit the post with a fix (or if you don't, I will next week).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thank you mate ^^ I'll see you next week :), cuz I don't how to fix it^^

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Sorry to bother you mate :) Please, if you have some time - can you fix it?^^